# How to trigger calculation on QGIS startup?

Tags: qgis, time, qfield, trigger

I am preparing a field worker / QField project an would like to visualize green spaces based on the days that have elapsed since the last field worker has visited that site.

I am testing with a very basic data set with a field beeing automatically updated with the current date by `now()` on insert and update. The elapsed days since the last visit are beeing calculated via

```
day(age(now(), "Date"))
```

Now I would like to update the days elapsed since the last visit on a daily basis or on every QGIS/QField startup. Do you have any idea, how to trigger the above calculation automatically when starting the QGIS project?

[image: visualization based on date]

Comment: You may run the classification based on the expression you use to create the field - so no need to recalculate. Though I do not know, how this can be transported to QField. Otherwise, have a look at virtual layers.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are looking for is a virtual field. It is a field based on an expression that is always evaluated and not stored in memory.

To do it you have to open the field calculator check the box `Create a virtual field` and then add your expression. `day(age(now(), "Date"))`. This field will always be calculated when you see it.

Your date must be in appropriate format (your date stored are may be just a date format you use). Even if you store your date in a non-standard date format you can to transform it to be understand by QGIS. For your example the transformation should be `make_date( right ("Date",4), left(right ("Date",7),2),left ("Date",2))`.

I think it should work in Qfield, but I have never tried.

Comment: Thank you - gonna check this out and give report.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I can confirm this is both working in QGIS and QField. Somehow on your mobile device you must restart the project from local file/folder not from the list of previously opened projects to see the updated calcultaion.