# Auto updating rule based symbology categorised by date

Tags: qgis, symbology, date, rule-based, rule

I have a shapefile of "Detection Points". These have a "strength" attribute and a "date" on which each was made. Data collection is ongoing - that is it began in April and will continue for a number of months from now.

To date I have just been displaying it as **categorised** by date which follows a suitable colour ramp. I do not know how to have QGIS automatically re-classify the data to have the categorised dates automaically update, but this hasn't been an issue so far as it has been easy to delete all and re-classify to make sure the colour ramp is up to date each day.

I now wish to use  **rule based** symbology so that we can display/not display points based on their strength - but I want to maintain the colour ramp which fades as the date becomes more distant in the past.
Updating this manually each day seems like more work than it needs to be.

I have made some rules which seem to get me most of the way there.

However, can anyone help by explaining how I can set my rules/categorisation so that it automatically re-classifies the data by date each day/time the project is opened so that the colour ramp automatically updates?

I have played around with making date a virtual field, but I guess I'm missing a big step in programming a basic rule.

I've got to this stage by creating a basic " Strength = '' " rule and then refining each rule and adding categories.

Screenshots below are the output with the fading colour ramp as displayed, and the basic rule I have put together which needs to be auto updating in terms of the categorised dates.
(Note - the screenshot has Date_Virt from me playing with making date a virutal field, but is can also just be Date).

[image: Output with fading colour ramp]

[image: Current Rule]

Comment: Don't use date directly, use age.

Comment: Thanks Erik.
That makes sense in theory - however I have no idea how to do so.
I assume it would involve a " now( ) " type relationship but my rule creation/programming knowledge is effectively zero...I'd really appreciate being stepped through it a bit.
Trying to learn more, but it's a slow process.

Comment: I have found this and will be trying to work through my question from it - thanks for the idea!
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401501/how-to-trigger-calculation-on-qgis-startup/401520

Comment: Your rules would be something like `1 < day(age(now(),"datecolumn")) < 3` - this should return everything from the day before yesterday.